# How to call an unreliable API repeatedly? Will Completable Future be helpful than writing standard try catch block running in a thread?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, architecture, runnable, completable-future

I have to call a critical API over a network (which makes it unreliable) many number of times in a go, many times a day. If the API fails to respond (timeout) or returns an error (because that server is in turn calling other unreliable third parties) i have to notify them about the error and then call the original API again.

Here, the error notifying may fail too and i will have to retry notifying error until i succeed. After which i can call the original API again.

I wanted to frame this using CompletableFuture. Is it a right choice of library for this kind of code? Or should i put a try catch loop in an infinite loop packed in a Runnable and execute it? Will CompletableFuture be an overkill? Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Is this a question about the Java standard library? or some other library? Also, when you say, "completable future," Are you talking specifically about the `CompletableFuture.runAsync(...)` or `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(...)` library calls?

Comment: This question describes some high-level requirements, and then asks about the appropriateness of using a certain, low-level library feature. Somewhat like describing details of how you want to furnish a home for a family of four, and then asking whether it is appropriate to use bricks in the construction. Voting to close as "too broad." Come back when you have a specific question about how something works (or why something didn't work the way you expected to work).  Or, try https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ if you're looking for answers to architectural questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly, the question is too broad, because the answer really depends on what frameworks you are already using.
The thing is -  there are many popular frameworks today that provide implementation of retry logic out of the box.

For example:

- if you're calling "critical API" via feign, then there is a [built-in support for retry](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#retry).
- if you're using Spring's `RestTemplate`, then you might also use [Spring Retry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry)
- if you just need simple retry utilities, there are number of libraries like [failsafe](http://jodah.net/failsafe/) and [guava-retrying](https://github.com/rholder/guava-retrying)

However, if after considering alternatives you decided implement retrying manually with `CompletableFuture`, you definitely can do this.

For example, here are simple utilities to retry:

- Unlimited number of times:

```
public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> retry(Throwable throwable, Function<Throwable, T> operation) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> operation.apply(throwable))
            .thenApply(CompletableFuture::completedFuture)
            .exceptionally(error -> retry(error, operation))
            .thenCompose(Function.identity());
}
```

Note: Here I assume, you can make some decision based on the instance of `Throwable`. Therefore, `operation` takes error as input and produces some useful result as an output. In your case, error - might be `critical API` call error, or `notification error`, useful result - successful `critical API` result.

- Fixed number of times (`MAX_RETRIES` in this case):

```
public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> retry(Throwable throwable, Function<Throwable, T> operation, int retry) {
    if (retry == MAX_RETRIES) return failedFuture(throwable);

    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> operation.apply(throwable))
            .thenApply(CompletableFuture::completedFuture)
            .exceptionally(error -> retry(error, operation, retry + 1))
            .thenCompose(Function.identity());
}

public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> failedFuture(Throwable throwable) {
    final CompletableFuture<T> failedFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
    failedFuture.completeExceptionally(throwable);
    return failedFuture;
}
```